# Surjectivity of a Cartesian product of functions, given surjectivity of (some) components

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

The following comes from the proof of Lemma 1, Section 9.3 (page 242) of Luenberger's Optimization by Vector Space Methods.

As a preliminary definition, recall a regular point of a transformation is defined as follows (can be found in Section 9.2 of Luenberger):

Let $T$ be a continuously Frechet differentiable transformation from an open set $D$ in a Banach space $X$ into a Banach space $Y$. If $x_{0} \in D$ is such that $T'(x_{0})$ maps $X$ onto $Y$, the point $x_{0}$ is said to be a regular point of the transformation $T$.

My question regards one of the steps in the proof of Lemma 1:

$\textbf{Lemma 1}$: Let $f$ be a real valued functional on a Banach space $X$ and $H$ a mapping from $X$ into a Banach space $Z$. Let $f$ achieve a local extremum subject to $H(x) = \theta$ at the point $x_{0}$ and assume that $f$ and $H$ are continuously Frechet differentiable in an open set containing $x_{0}$ and that $x_{0}$ is a regular point of $H$.  Then $f'(x_{0})h=0$ for all $h$ satisfying $H'(x_{0})h = \theta$.

The proof is given as the following, up to the point of confusion:

$\textbf{Proof}$: To be specific, assume that the local extremum is a local minimum.  Consider the transformation $T:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times Z$ defined by $T(x) = (f(x),H(x))$.  If there were an $h$ such that $H'(x_{0})h = \theta$, $f'(x_{0})h \neq 0$, then $T'(x_{0}) = (f'(x_{0}),H'(x_{0})):X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times Z$ would be onto $\mathbb{R} \times Z$ since  $H'(x_{0})$ is onto $Z$.

My question is regards this last line which seems to say the following:

$\textbf{Statement}$: If $A:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $B:X \rightarrow Z$ are linear operators, with $B$ onto, then $(A,B):X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times Z$ is onto.

However this seems incorrect for the following reason.  Since $B$ is onto we know for any $z' \in Z$ there exists $x' \in X$ such that $B(x') = z'$.  Additionally, $A(x') = \alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(A,B)(x') = (\alpha,z')$.  However for $(A,B):X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times Z$ to be onto there has to be an element in $X$ mapping to $(\beta,z')$ for any $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$.  Normally, for a non-zero mapping into $\mathbb{R}$ we can get to any non-zero element by a scaling argument, i.e. $A(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}x') = \beta$. However, there is no guarantee $B(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}x') = z'$ and therefore no way of concluding $(A,B)$ is surjective.

My question is the following: Is the above $\textbf{statement}$ in fact true, and if so how can it be proved?

Comment: The statement is false. Counterexample: $A=0$. However, if $A\neq 0$, the statement is true because then $A$ is onto. To see this, let $x\in X$ such that $Ax\neq 0$. Choose any $y\in\mathbb R$ and observe $A(\frac{y}{Ax}x) = \frac{y}{Ax}Ax = y$.

Comment: I see that $A$ is onto so long as $A \neq 0$ (this was the scaling argument I was trying to get at below the statement).  However even if both $A$ and $B$ are onto, I don't see how we know $(A,B):X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times Z$ is onto.  It seems like it would be possible to miss elements of $\mathbb{R} \times Z$. For example if an element of $Z$ is only mapped to by one $x \in X$, then $(A,B)(x) = (\alpha, z)$ and trying to hit some other element of $\mathbb{R}$ means we no longer hit $z$.

Comment: True. What you need is some $x_0\in\ker B\backslash\ker A$. Then $(A,B)$ is onto. To see this, let $(y,z)\in\mathbb R\times Z$. Then there is $x'$ such that $Bx' = z$. Hence,$$(A,B)\Big(x' + \frac{y-Ax'}{Ax_0}x_0\Big) = \Big(Ax' + \frac{y-Ax'}{Ax_0}Ax_0,Bx'\Big) = (y,z).$$

Comment: Ah I see your point in regards to the statement, thank you.  It still seems to me though that the proof in Luenberger is missing a step, that $\text{ker}(H'(x_{0})) - \text{ker}(f'(x_{0}))$ is non-trivial.

Comment: The vector $h$ is in that set. So, the proof is ok. (I assume that $\theta$ means the zero vector)

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thank you!